# Python Matplotlib crashes on ploting

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a problem with matplotlib on my os x Mavericks. when I want to plot, the figure window appears but I don't see any plot in it. Apparently, it has crashed or something since it is also non responsive. I can see the circling os x figure also.

Fig window: https://www.dropbox.com/s/oasrf22crgtjr6u/Screenshot%202015-02-16%2001.04.10.png?dl=0

The command I have entered is this:
`plt.hist([1,2,3])`

I am using matplotlib 1.4.2, iPython 2.3.1, and Python 2.7.

UPDATE: This problem doesn't occur when I use regular Python interpreter. Only when I am using iPython.

Appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly from the matplotlib website:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3,])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.show()
```

This works for me.

Have you imported matplotlib?
Are you running ipython with qtconsole?
Have you updated everything?

Comment: I have imported everything.
I am using Pycharm and when I installed iPython the default interpreter in Pycharm changed to iPython. Don't know what you mean by qtconsole.
Also, I think everything related is up to date.

Comment: When loading python from terminal, load it with "ipython qtconsole" and the graphs should appear.

Comment: If you're not using anaconda, I suggest you download it. It has a ton of packages and lets you know when things are out of date.

Comment: Thanks. It worked.
I hadn't installed 'pyqt' and 'pygments'. After installing them everything worked just fine.

Comment: Great :) Have fun with your project!